# MySQL procedure: change between EXISTS and NOT EXISTS by evaluating an input param?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a MySQL procedure.  I'm doing something like this:

```
IF aninputparam = 1 THEN
    SELECT blah 
    FROM blah
    JOIN etc etc
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mysubquery)
ELSE
    SELECT allthesamestuff
    FROM allthesametables
    JOIN allthesamejoins
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT samesubquery)
END IF
```

That works, but it offends my artistic sensibilities and is contrary to DRY principles, not to mention an example of the cut-and-paste architectural antipattern.  Can I do something like

```
@x = concat(
    'SELECT blah FROM blah JOIN etc WHERE ', 
    IF(aninputparam = 1, 'EXISTS', 'NOT EXISTS'), 
    ' (SELECT mysubquery)'
 );
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @x; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

And if so, are there any disadvantages to preparing the SQL statement dynamically that way?  (And might there be a better way to do it that I don't know about?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few reasons why you might opt not to compose a dynamic query:

1. Writing dynamic queries inside stored procedures makes it more likely that you'll create a SQL injection vulnerability. This does not appear to be the case with your code example, but it's definitely a risk if you start writing dynamic queries on a large scale.
2. MySQL pre-compiles the execution plan of stored procedures and executes the query from cache. This provides optimal performance. Dynamic queries cannot be cached in this manner as they must be built at run-time for every request.
3. It can be more difficult to debug dynamic queries when something goes wrong. You can get syntax errors at runtime that would've otherwise been caught at compile time for a static stored procedure.

It might use more lines of code, but your first example is fine. It's easier to understand than your second example and doesn't have any of the drawbacks I've listed above.

Furthermore, I wouldn't say that your first code example violates DRY principles. The two queries do two different things. However, your second example may well violate the KISS principle.

Comment: Good observations, thank you.  Now that you mention it, KISS is more important than DRY usually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a count to handle both exists and not exists scenarios:

```
select foo
from bar
where @param = (select case when count(*) > 1 then 1 else 0 end from ...)
```

The problem is that these kinds of flexible queries don't always produce optimal plans and they also often obfuscate the intention. The alternative of dynamic sql has a lot of downsides too. (I now see that that was your main question.) So despite the worries about repeating yourself it's really often just the better way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be through `JOIN`s:

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (x INTEGER);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2);

CREATE TABLE bar (x INTEGER);
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (1);
```

**Uncorrelated Condition**:
For an uncorrelated condition, use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  f.*
FROM
  foo f
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
      SIGN(COUNT(1)) n
    FROM
      bar b
  ) a
WHERE
  a.n = 1  -- 1: EXISTS, 0: NOT EXISTS

| x |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
```

**Correlated Condition**:
If the condition needs to be correlated to the driving table, use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  f.*
FROM
  foo f
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      b.x, SIGN(COUNT(1)) n
    FROM
      bar b
    GROUP BY
      b.x
  ) a ON (
    a.x = f.x
  )
WHERE
  COALESCE(a.n, 0) = 0  -- 1: EXISTS, 0: NOT EXISTS

| x |
|---|
| 2 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22eaa/21)

Comment: This is interesting.  I'm looking for either all the records in foo that are in bar, or all the records in foo that aren't in bar (the use case is adding or removing child relations from a parent entity, presenting the user with a list of either records that can be added or records that can be removed), which result is given by your correlated condition.  I'll study it and figure out why.  What does the `SIGN(COUNT(1))` do exactly?

Comment: `SIGN(COUNT(1))` returns `1` when there is one or more rows for the key in `bar` (could have been written as `CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`). If there are no rows in `bar` for the key, then the `LEFT JOIN` returns `NULL` which is why in the correlated case the `COALESCE` is required rather than just being able to directly compare to `0` as in the uncorrelated case.

Comment: Ok, I get it.  I've never used `SIGN` before, so I looked it up.  Simple enough.  I hadn't seen `COUNT(1)` before either; it would seem the debate continues as to whether it is really an optimized version of `COUNT(*)` or not.  Nice alternative, thanks for posting it.  I went to your fiddle and checked the execution plan for the `WHERE EXISTS` alternative.  They are quite different, so in larger contexts it would be wise to check the plans of both approaches.

Comment: I've always had an aversion to using the `*` version, probably because using a `1` generalises a bit more directly if you're doing conditional counts like `COUNT(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 END)`, but I don't believe any modern database would treat it any differently (must check one day!). Also, agree that the plan for my query would be quite different, and it is less likely that a DB vendor would optimise it as directly as in the case of an explicit `EXISTS`.